# Extracting likes and loves from facebook using facepager

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hoping someone could help me. I'm using Facepager and I'm seeking to extract the likes, loves, and wows from a picture or video on Facebook. How do I do that if some photos are 24k likes?

Comment: What have you tried? And you are aware of Facebook does not allow scraping?

Comment: I actually had found a way to do it, but I forgot what I did.

Comment: That doesn't answer either of my questions.